# Bucket analysis in SSIS Derived column

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have a do a bucket analysis of some days calculation in SSIS staging

please help me in fixing this

```
DAYS <=90 = 0-3 Months
DAYS >=91 &&  DAYS <=180 = 3-6 Months
else > 6 Months
```

which I tried to frame like below but not working, and i am very new to this, please suggest

```
(DAYS <="90") ? "0-3 Months": ((DAYS >= "91") &&  (DAYS <= "180") ? "3-6 Months": "> 6 Months")
```

Comment: Hi EzLo did you mean like this ([DA_BUCKET_DAYS]<=90) ? "0-3 Months": ([DA_BUCKET_DAYS]>= 91) &&  [DA_BUCKET_DAYS] <= 180) ? "3-6 Months": "> 6 Months"

Comment: Yes, that should be OK. If it still doesn't work that way then add some sample data so we can troubleshoot.

Comment: Hi EzLo, Thank you I did that  and it still came up with error, but  ([DA_BUCKET_DAYS]<=90) ? "0-3 Months": ([DA_BUCKET_DAYS]>= 91) && [DA_BUCKET_DAYS] <= 180) ? "3-6 Months": "> 6 Months" removed the ( ) and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparisons should be against numbers, not strings (they shouldn't have the enclosing "). Other than that, the expression seems OK.

Make sure that `DAYS` is of an integer type and not `STR` (or `WSTR`) because comparing numbers behave different than comparing strings. You can try casting `DAYS` to `I8` before the comparison if its a string type.

Answer (score 0):

Please go this way ,it might help you in this case .
Same thing I have already used in one of My project same logic.

LoadDate== DATEDDIFF(dd,LoadDate,Getdate())<=90 ? "0-3 Months DAYS" : LoadDate== DATEDDIFF(dd,LoadDate,Getdate())>91 ? "0-6 Months DAYS" : "Other"